# python 3.5 ICMP socket not working on Windows

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, network-programming, network-protocols

I'm trying to make traceroute implementation in python 3.5. On linux this code works fine. On Windows 10 I have infinity waiting of ICMP packet. Wireshark see ICMP packet in Windows.

```
import socket

# Create a UDP and ICMP sockets
receiver = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.getprotobyname('ICMP'))

sender = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sender.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_TTL, 1)

server_address = (socket.gethostbyname('google.com'), 33434)

try:
    # Send data
    receiver.bind(("", 33434))
    sent = sender.sendto(b"", server_address)
    data, server = receiver.recvfrom(512)
    print('received "%s"\n"%s"' % (data, server[0]))
finally:
    print('closing socket')
    sender.close()
    receiver.close()
```

Comment: Did you check it is not simply a firewall issue (Windows 10 blocking the return packet)?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm sure this is not a firewall issue.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, additional configuration on the socket itself is required to make this work, the [fifth example on the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example) contains the following that served as the hints for making [this ping server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76319940/) work:

```py
# the public network interface
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
s.bind((HOST, 0))
# Include IP headers
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
# receive all packets
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)
```

With that in mind, `receiver.bind(("", 33434))` will not work as the hostname of the host must be passed instead of empty string, and that `IP_TTL` is configured using `socket.IPPROTO_IP` actually.  Since implementation of something like `traceroute` was mentioned as an objective in the question, a rough implementation of that (that doesn't guard against other random non-related ICMP that might come back) might look something like this:

```py
import os
import socket
import sys

# Create a UDP and ICMP sockets
receiver = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.getprotobyname('ICMP'))
sender = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

if os.name == 'nt':
    # include additional configuration required for Windows
    host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    receiver.bind((host, 0))
    receiver.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
    receiver.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

host = sys.argv[1] if sys.argv[1:] else 'example.com'
server_address = socket.gethostbyname(host)
print("tracing host %r ip %s" % (host, server_address))

try:
    # Send data
    for ttl in range(1, 11):
        sender.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_TTL, ttl)
        # send UDP to traceroute port 33434
        sent = sender.sendto(b"", (server_address, 33434))
        data, addr = receiver.recvfrom(512)
        print('received %d bytes from %r' % (len(data), addr[0]))
finally:
    print('closing socket')
    sender.close()
    receiver.close()
```

Usage is simply like this (incidentally the machine that ran this was exactly 10 hops away from the example host - the range of TTL the above script will send is from 1 to 10):

```console
$ sudo python script.py 'example.com'
tracing host 'example.com' ip 93.184.216.34
received 56 bytes from '192.168.178.1'
...
received 56 bytes from '93.184.216.34'
closing socket
```

Note that with this modification, `socket.bind` is no longer called for Linux (as demoed above) but this will still work correctly there.  Port isn't actually used for ICMP so this is left as `0`.  Also, due to the usage of raw sockets, administrative privileges is typically required.  Oh right, the question is above Windows, let's try that:

```console
C:\Windows\system32>python E:\script.py example.com
tracing host 'example.com' ip 93.184.216.34
received 56 bytes from '10.0.2.2'
...
received 56 bytes from '93.184.216.34'
closing socket
```

Note that I had to turn the firewall off (Windows Defender) in order to be able receive the raw packets, and that `cmd.exe` was opened as Administrator in order to gain usage of raw sockets.